# How to read the binaries from AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I am trying to store my AEM binaries to a local cloud storage which have certain API. I can write a code to send my data from java to that cloud but i am not sure about reading the binaries from AEM. I think i have to take care of all other task too like modify delete download e.t.c. is it possible? I mean for amazon S3 they have connector. it is like writing my own connector.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "no".

What you are asking for in AEM world is a custom data store connecter. Binaries go in DataStore (if configured). Writing a custom binary storage apart from file or S3 will have a few issues as below:

- Lot of additional house keeping tasks will need to be written. For example DataStore garbage collection for your custom store.
- Connecting NodeStore to references in custom data store (consider implementing an equivalent of S3 key or file system path for your implementation)
- Backup/restore synchronisation logic.
- Clustering support
- Consistency checks and recovery options
- Caching requirements for AEM's caching plugins.
- Adobe may not support it
- Future upgrades will be tricky

It might be prudent to contact your Adobe support for getting more info on this as they might suggest an alternative solution to meet your requirements.

Edit: Some cloud storage providers implement S3 compatible APIs so it might be worth asking your provider if they have something like this.

Edit: If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-aws-ext/2.8.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/aws/ext/ds/S3DataStore.java#S3DataStore) you will see that the CachingDataStore does not allow any override hooks for modifying the file names during read/write operations.

Comment: What is HTH? yes, our cloud storage uses API same as S3. apart from this,it is way different from Amazon s3 and that is why we have to write a custom connector.

Comment: If yours cloud storage provides S3 API then the S3 connecter should be good for you as it works with compatible API and doesn't care about implementation. However, be warned, that most S3 API implementations out there are not 100% compatible and end up with some issues.

Comment: Forgot to answer first part.. HTH means 'Hope this Helps'

Comment: We use s3 api but we can't use the connector provided by AEM because S3 stores data in a flat file structure. we have a limitation, we need to make new folder after a specific limit.

Comment: Ah ok, then I would suggest to contact the Adobe support to ask them for help in customising or advising on this as the S3 connecter is proprietary and too many hidden parts (as per my answer above) than can have an impact on the solution. In my head, it seems a bit too complex, risky and expensive without verifying product compatibility from all the vendors.